# $\Bbb{Q} \bigcap [0,1]\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^NI_j$, show $\sum_{j=1}^N|I_j|\ge1$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is

> Let $\{I_1,I_2,...,I_n\}$ be a finite family of intervals in $\Bbb{R}$ such that $\Bbb{Q} \bigcap [0,1]\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^NI_j$, show $\sum_{j=1}^N|I_j|\ge1$ where $|I_j|$ is the Lebesgue measure of $I_j$. Is this true when the faimily of intervals is infinite?

I have been thinking about this problem for an hour and could not get a clear clue. My guess is that if $\sum_{j=1}^N|I_j|<1$, then $\bigcup_{j=1}^NI_j\bigcap[0,1]$ must not be a cover of $[0,1]$ and hence some rationals are left out, but how do I show this formally? Can anyone provide a hint or reference? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the expression $\Bbb{Q} \bigcap [0,1]\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^NI_j$ take closure on both the sides and find the measure of both the sides. Note that taking closure and taking measure are monotone.

Comment: Thank you. That's a brilliant proof. Now $\overline {\Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]}  = [0,1] \subset \overline {\bigcup\nolimits_{j = 1}^N {{I_j}} }  = \bigcup\nolimits_{j = 1}^N {\overline {{I_j}} } $, thus $1 \le \sum\limits_{j = 1}^N {\left| {\overline {{I_j}} } \right|}  = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^N {\left| {{I_j}} \right|} $

Comment: I still have a question. In the infinite case $\bigcup\nolimits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\overline {{I_j}} }  \ne \overline {\bigcup\nolimits_{j = 1}^\infty  {{I_j}} } $ but $\bigcup\nolimits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\overline {{I_j}} }  \subseteq \overline {\bigcup\nolimits_{j = 1}^\infty  {{I_j}} } $.  Is it because of this that $1 \le  \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty {\left| {{I_j}} \right|} $ does not hold in the infinite case?

Comment: We have countable sub additivity  no? please ask your this doubt little bit more precisely. I cant get.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the finite case after taking closure on both sides, we have $[0,1] \in  \overline {\bigcup\nolimits_{j = 1}^N  {{I_j}} }=\bigcup\nolimits_{j = 1}^N {\overline {{I_j}} }$, then we can take the measure and use the subadditivity. However, in the infinite case, after taking the closure on both sides, we only have $[0,1] \in   \overline {\bigcup\nolimits_{j = 1}^\infty  {{I_j}} } \ne \bigcup\nolimits_{j = 1}^\infty {\overline {{I_j}} }$, then we cannot use the countable sub-additivity here?

Comment: are you thinking about proving the same result for infinite family of intervals? for infinite family this result is not true.

Comment: Hi, yes. It is not true. I am not proving it but need to show a reason why it is not true. So I am asking is it not true due to the additivity does not hold for the infinite case.

Comment: you can explicitly construct an infinite family of open intervals which covers even whole rationals whose sum of the intervals is strictly less than one.